# meteor.js page refresh on load more button click

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I implemented load more button functionality from Discover Meteor book. When I have either loading template or iron-router-progress, when I click on the button, it does page refresh and scrollbar goes to the top of the page. When I do not have loading template, or iron-router-progress, it works smoothly. What am I doing wrong?